# boost guidelines for includes/headers

Tags: boost

Are there official rules/guidelines for including boost headers? I'm wondering as up until recently I almost always used the format `#include <boost/library.hpp>`. Then I came across **Boost.Timer**, whose documentation states that there are 2 versions of the library, a deprecated and a new one.

The deprecated version resides in `<boost/timer.hpp>` whereas the new one resides in `<boost/timer/timer.hpp>`. The two version seemingly exist without any interaction...

So I thought: "well obviously one should prefer the 'internal' headers". So I looked at some of my more regularly used headers and noticed that for example `<boost/format.hpp>` simply includes the headers of `boost/format` plus several external dependencies. So including the specific headers doesn't seem like the best idea.

So I thought: "well maybe that's a transitional artifact and they're working towards the `boost/library/header'`scheme".

The I noticed the new **Boost.Atomics** library - only just recently added - and was stunned: there's a header `boost/atomics.hpp` and a folder with headers of the same name.

Now I'm somewhat confused: Is there an official guideline on which headers are to be considered public (similar to the standard headers) and where the internal aspects of the api starts? Or is it completely up to the library to decide the structure of it's headers?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the [Boost Library Requirements and Guidelines](http://www.boost.org/development/requirements.html) does not define the scoping and separation of header files.  The [Boost Header Policy](http://www.boost.org/development/header.html) defines guidelines to allow headers to co-exist with other headers.  Nevertheless, many of the libraries provide a distinction by:

- Providing separate files for logical divisions of types/functionality users may want.
- Placing header files internal to the library within a `detail` directory.
- Declaring internal types, functions, etc. in a `detail` namespace.

Some even make another level of distinction by separating a function declaration from its  definition within header files by placing the definition in an `impl` directory.

It is suppose to be safe to include the highest-level header file.  Additionally, it should generally be safe to include more specific files.  For example:

- If I want `boost::thread`, `boost::mutex`, and `boost::lock`, or do not mind the additional includes, then I may include `boost/thread.hpp`.
- If I only want `boost::thread`, then I would include `boost/thread/thread_only.hpp`.  I would not directly include `boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp`.